# browser new window (window.open) can't load using javafx

Tags: java, javafx, webview, webkit, javafx-webengine

```
   engine.setCreatePopupHandler(new Callback<PopupFeatures, WebEngine>() { // todo should create a new tab.
  @Override public WebEngine call(PopupFeatures popupFeatures) {
      Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
      WebView wv2 = new WebView();
      engine.load(getView().getEngine().getLocation());
      stage.setScene(new Scene(wv2));
      stage.setX(stage.getX() + 250);
      stage.setY(stage.getY() + 100);
      stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
      stage.show();
    System.out.println("Popup: " + popupFeatures);
  return wv2.getEngine();
  }
});
```

Above is my code.
I made my own browser it's all functionality working and through this code
new window is open but the web page functionality is not working on new engine.
how can i do it again and again create new engine dynamically.
Please help me and sorry for poor english.
Thank you

Comment: Why are you reloading the existing page (I think) with `engine.load(getView().getEngine().getLocation());`? Can you describe what "the web page functionality is not working on new engine" means: this seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: I want to open new window but again reopen new window from the new window then it will nots works for me.
please open the below link.
[a link]http://hist.laarcampus.com/texting.html[a link]